# What is the use of MediaElement.UnloadedBehavior in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I know that by setting `LoadedBehavior="Play"`, media will be played instantly after the container window appears. Or `LoadedBehavior="Pause"` will show the first frame and remains in *paused* state. But what I can't figure out is the use of setting values other than `Close` for `UnloadedBehavior`. However, setting `UnloadedBehavior="Close"` doesn't cause the media screen go blank automatically.

The [MSDN page for UnloadedBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.unloadedbehavior?view=netframework-4.7.2) has almost nothing to help.
I've also read these MSDN pages:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/multimedia-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediastate?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

UnloadedBehavior="Close" is very useful Behavior.

When you want to remove a mediaelement , You must release the memory and all media resources that it has used.

You should know Microsoft's description of [Unloaded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded?view=netframework-4.7.2) .

Suppose your mediaelement is a children of a grid and you want to remove it , Then there are 2 ways to free up memory:

1 - using Unloaded Event like this :

```
private void mediaelement_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                  mediaelement.Unloaded -= mediaelement_Unloaded;
                  mediaelement.Source = null;
                  mediaelement.Close();
            }
```

2 - instead of above solution you can simply set UnloadedBehavior="Close"
,So it will [close the media and releas all media resources (including video memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediastate?view=netframework-4.7.2)) automatically .

.......................
**UPDATE :**

Microsoft about UnloadedBehavior says:
"UnloadedBehavior. In place when media is unloaded. This ensures that all media resources are released by default, even when a MediaClock is associated with the MediaElement."

But , I'm agree with Mostafa because I couldn't find a clear document about another UnloadedBehaviors like play ,pause and stop.

Comment: Thanks, but what about `Play` value for it?

Comment: @Mostafa F ,sorry , I don't know exactly , my answer updated.

Comment: @Mostafa F , I think your question is a good one , I hope an expert will answer this question with  clarity.